# /usr/bin/kde-print-queue requires sudo rights - how to let normal use pause printer?

Tags: kde, printing, non-root-user

I need to let a user without general sudo rights pause and unpause a printer.

The command is:

```
/usr/bin/kde-print-queue HP_Printer1
```

However, the problem is shown here:

```
"HP_Printer1" NOT m_printerPaused
libkcups: Pause-Printer last error: 1025 Forbidden
libkcups: Calling cupsDoAuthentication() password_retries: 0
libkcups: Called cupsDoAuthentication(), success: true
libkcups: 1
libkcups: true
libkcups: Pause-Printer last error: 1025 Forbidden
```

adding sudo rights for this user for /usr/bin/kde-print-queue did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution:

add this normal user to the lpadmin group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G lpadmin joe
```

(FWIW< I had previously used visudo to give joe sudo rights to /usr/bin/kde-print-queue and I did not revoke that privilege.)